# SYBASE execute SQLstatement in a procedure

Tags: sql, cursor, procedure, sap-ase

I'm writing a procedure for dynamic SQL

```
CREATE PROC ...
AS
DECLARE
... 
BEGIN TRANSACTION migrate_uuid
    ...
    EXEC('DECLARE u_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM ' || @table_name) 

    OPEN u_cursor

    ...
```

I cannot OPEN u_cursor. I will receive the message: 
**"The cursor 'u_cursor' can not be used as it could not be found. It is possible that either it was not declared or it is not available in the current
context."**

How to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually create a 'dynamically defined' cursor in Sybase ASE. 
First, the reason why your example fails is that the cursor is declared inside the EXEC, which is nested scope compared to the outer block and therefore the cursor is not accessible outside the EXEC.
In principle, you could wrap the entire cursor declaration plus open-fetch-close in the EXEC (best put it all in a string variable first), but then another issue will kick in related to how a cursor can (not) be declared, which by itself is unrelated to the EXEC but will cause it to fail anyway.

The only workarounds include tricks like definign the cursor on a view but redefining the view to point to another table, but this will have various issues and limitations as ell.

Answer (score 0):

In most RDBMSs the code run by `EXEC` (or its equivalent) is in its own scope. Any variables and handles created in code executed by the `EXEC` only exist in that scope.

You need to either run everything in the `EXEC` or none of it. You cannot mix and match. Given you want to parametrise on a table name, you'll need to execute all the code in the `EXEC`.

Comment: So, If I want to declare cursor with dynamic table name without using EXEC, how I can do that?

Comment: @TamNguyen you cannot in general, any approach in an RDBMS will be specific to that RDBMS (and I expect most do not support it).

Comment: OK. Thanks for your support! It's very helpful for me